# What should I call the object returned from a Truffle contract function-call

Tags: web3js, truffle, transactions, receipts

When I perform a contract function-call via Truffle, and then resolve the returned promise, I get something like this:

```
{
    "tx": "0x...",
    "receipt": {
        "transactionHash": "0x...",
        "transactionIndex": 0,
        "blockHash": "0x...",
        "blockNumber": 24,
        "gasUsed": 42860,
        "cumulativeGasUsed": 42860,
        "contractAddress": null,
        "logs": [
            {
                "logIndex": 0,
                "transactionIndex": 0,
                "transactionHash": "0x...",
                "blockHash": "0x...",
                "blockNumber": 24,
                "address": "0x...",
                "data": "0x...",
                "topics": [
                    "0x...",
                    "0x...",
                    "0x..."
                ],
                "type": "mined"
            }
        ],
        "status": "0x1",
        "logsBloom": "0x..."
    },
    "logs": [
        {
            "logIndex": 0,
            "transactionIndex": 0,
            "transactionHash": "0x...",
            "blockHash": "0x...",
            "blockNumber": 24,
            "address": "0x...",
            "type": "mined",
            "event": "Transfer",
            "args": {
                "from": "0x...",
                "to": "0x...",
                "value": "0"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I'm not really sure how exactly Truffle wraps web3.js in order to invoke contract functions, so I'm not really sure where to look in the web3.js documentation. But I am using Truffle v4.1.14, which relies on web3.js v0.18.4, and [the docs for web3.js v0.x](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3js-api-reference) are kinda hard to read, so I searched in [the docs for web3.js v1.x](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/) instead.

Now, I guess I should be looking into [web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth.html#eth-sendsignedtransaction), which returns:

> A promise combined event emitter. Will be resolved when the transaction [receipt](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth.html#eth-gettransactionreceipt-return) is available.

So it seems that Truffle takes this receipt, and embeds it into a JSON object which contains the following **additional** fields:

1. `tx`, which is the transaction hash, I suppose
2. `logs`, which contains some or all of the `receipt.logs`, but decoded

So what exactly is going on here?

This new object is certainly not the receipt described in the docs.

Is there an official terminology for this, or is it just a "Truffle hack" designated to make my life easier decoding events?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clearly truffle returns it's own object. It will surely contain the original web3 receipt which is labeled `receipt` because truffle uses web3 0.x as you mentioned. So the added attributes are nothing more than a way of truffle trying to make its framework better and keep the layer above web3.

I don't think there is a certain terminology for that object, or at least it will always be overshadowed by the `transactionReceipt` of Web3, hence the same name take for both.

Comment: But if I were to try to keep my test code compatible outside of truffle (for example, suppose I have some common JS utilities that I want to use for "realtime" interaction with the Ethereum network), then I should probably avoid relying on that additional layer, correct?

Comment: yes, or you could write separate testing utilities for truffle and for the outside of truffle. it is not that hard, considering it is just a json attribute away.

Comment: I decided that the name `response` would be suitable enough. Then I can refer to `response.tx`, `response.logs`, `response.receipt`, `response.receipt.logs`, etc.

Comment: BTW, would you have any idea how Truffle is able to extract the event name from the receipt? In the example above, it is in `response.logs[0].event`.